# Информация по MVC

Tags: mvc

Уже не первый раз встречаюсь с MVC в статьях. Очень интересно было бы узнать побольше об этом. Найти достаточно адекватный источник пока не удалось. Практически каждая статья пытается толковать об этом по своему. Поэтому хочется увидеть названия адекватных книг, ссылки на статьи, возможно хорошее разъяснение темы.

Comment: Еще интересно насколько адекватна статья
http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/php/31270/

Comment: Статья неадекват. Т.е. писать софт она позволит... Но качество будет ой-ой-ой.

Comment: Прочитал все ответы. Увы ни один мне не помог. Да и я не просил мне предлагать фреймворки, меня интересовало именно php решение без надстроек. Совет почитать Фаулера внес некоторую ясность, но в итоге мне помогли разобраться с той статьей о которой я спросил чуть выше. Спасибо всем за ответы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Фаулер:

- [GUI Architectures](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html)

Переводы:

- [Часть 1](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/personal/50830/#habracut)
- [Часть 2](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/personal/53536/#habracut)

Answer (score 3):

[Developing a Spring Framework MVC application step-by-step](http://static.springsource.org/spring/articles/2005/MVC-step-by-step/Spring-MVC-step-by-step.html).

Comment: Советую этот вариант. Изучить паттерн MVC можно и на вики. А в случае со спрингом у вас есть шанс разобраться, как он работает на практике.

Answer (score 2):

А я б посоветовал взять фреймворк, например, kohana, codeigneter, zend и т.д., короче, любой посовременнее и изучить на его примере и MVC и HMVC :)

Comment: Я думаю, что это заблуждение. Нужно начинать не с фреймворка, а с попытки понять что же представляет собой MVC. Тем более, что такая глобальная концепция может быть реализована везде - хоть на С++, хоть на PHP. К тому же фреймворки бывают разной степени паршивости. Zend мне лично не нравится. Хорошая статья для попытки осмысления что есть что - http://blog.astrumfutura.com/2008/12/the-m-in-mvc-why-models-are-misunderstood-and-unappreciated/

Comment: Я тому, что, например, любимая мною, Кохана, очень хорошо MVC реализовала! И, пусть и разбросанный, но userguide есть. Главное - найти то, что надо, а написано нормально.

Answer (score 1):

Можете глянуть тут, неплохо написано: http://irbis-team.com/15/3/1

Answer (score 1):

[PureMVC](http://puremvc.org/) дает возможность попробовать MVC на практике. Библиотека написана на многих языках программирования и широко используется. Имеется подробная документация (в т.ч. и на русском)

Comment: (только сейчас заметил, что вопрос древний :) )

Answer (score 1):

Вот на примере [symfony](http://developer.co.ua/posts/view/glava_2_issleduem_kod_symfony).